# As a Magus with Psychic dedication, can I use Shield non-amped as a cantrip?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, magus

Taking the Psychic dedication I see Shield (amped) is listed as a Focus spell in Pathbuilder.

Can I cast it non amped as a cantrip? The dedication seems to say I can but the app doesn't automatically give it to me.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes

[Amping is optional](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=21):

> ...you **can** apply an amp only to a psi cantrip...

That's why Conscious Minds grant non-amped benefits to cantrips too, like the ability to target other people with Shield from [The Tangible Dream](https://2e.aonprd.com/ConsciousMinds.aspx?ID=5).

It takes a Focus Point to amp, so that's why Shield (amped) is under your Focus spells. It's possible that you just need to select the Shield cantrip with your Psychic dedication feat; double check that feat to make sure you've selected the right cantrip. If it's not displaying normally, then that's a bug and should be reported via their system.